# Minimum pom.xml file for new Maven / Spring MVC project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, pom.xml

I am completely new to Maven and Spring MVC. What I am looking to do is to set up a new Spring MVC project, using Maven (hopefully this sentence makes sense), and run my web app on Tomcat using Eclipse.

I am following the tutorial at this link and I have a problem with the `pom.xml` file:

- [Getting Started with Maven and Spring](http://spring.io/blog/2011/01/17/green-beans-getting-started-with-maven-and-spring/)

The tutorial asks to create the folder structure, and to create a pom.xml file. For starters they ask to put this line in pom.xml:

```
xml 4.0.0org.springsource.greenbeans.mavenexample11.0-SNAPSHOTOur Simple Project
```

But when I do that, my Eclipse throws an error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\projectName\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM D:\projectName\pom.xml: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not ` (position: START_DOCUMENT seen `... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
```

Any idea on what the right minimum pom.xml could be? I tried many things but it didn't work for me...

Answer (score 8):

You need not create folder structure yourself. Maven archtype 'maven-archetype-webapp' does it for you. Here is a good tutorial to guide you through for basic setting up a MVC project in eclipse (and the right approach):

- [Create Spring MVC dynamic web project with Maven and make it support Eclipse IDE](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/spring-maven-web-application-in-eclipse.html)

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.beingjavaguys.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleSpringMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SampleSpringMaven Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
      <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
      <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <finalName>SampleSpringMaven</finalName>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                  <server>my-tomcat</server>
                  <path>/SampleSpringMaven</path>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                  <target>${jdk.version}</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  ```

Comment: hey, I have an issue with the part "Run Spring Maven project in eclipse" : I only see junit. The trace of the command is the following : [...]   
 Using Eclipse Workspace: null
 Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER
 Not writing settings - defaults suffice
 File D:\Users\FirstMavenProject\.project already exists.
 Additional settings will be preserved, run mvn eclipse:clean if you want old settings to be removed. Wrote Eclipse project for "FirstMavenProject" to D:\Users\FirstMavenProject. Any idea why I am not getting all the .jars ?

Comment: If youbare working maven, i highly recommend usibg Intellij Idea rather than Eclipse. In Idea, all you have to do is open the pom.xml, and choose to open the concerned project when asked. Makes you life much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal `pom.xml` file for Spring MVC with Tomcat could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And then:

```
$ mvn -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8888 tomcat7:run
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mininum pom.xml for a non spring boot application which will generate a Spring 5, Java 11 war file which you can deploy on tomcat. I'm using the spring bom here in dependency management which locks the version of the spring framework jars

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.yourco</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-framework-bom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.9</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-mvc-demo</finalName>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
    </build>
</project>
```