# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException springservlet

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm studying tutorial about spring mvc.
i have a problem in this step : https://github.com/in28minutes/SpringMvcStepByStep/blob/master/Step11.md

i already copy paste the same code from the link(1st time typing according to the video but always get this error. already tried deployment assembly but none displayed or other things. could anyone help me why i got this eror? i'm using eclipse oxygen

```
Jun 27, 2018 9:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getServletContainerInitializer
SEVERE: The ServletContentInitializer [org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer] could not be created
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1668)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: For sample structure also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711056/minimum-pom-xml-file-for-new-maven-spring-mvc-project

Comment: ah thanks i could run the program but still have same error. the app works fine though

Comment: i tried to delete my springframework repository at local user and all the problems solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **pom.xml** should be at least like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependecies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Replace *${org.springframework-version}* with your version of Spring, if you need. ALso update the Java version if you know it's not *1.9*. Your **pom.xml** has to include the entire xml with `<dependencies>` section having at least **spring-webmvc**. Then run and verify Maven builds everything. Your project has missing dependencies. Verify your versions are set appropriately.